# How can I make this question more clear?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634226/is-there-a-term-for-this-property-of-operations-relationships) question earlier today and, while I understand it's a somewhat vague and abstract question—it doesn't strike me as *unclear*. I'd not be surprised if there are some misunderstandings, or a triviality/mixup I'm not seeing, but it's only been downvoted with a vote to close for being "unclear."

What can I do to clarify this question?

Comment: Is your $*$ a mapping $X\times X\to X$ or $X\to X$? If your example is "multiplication by $-1$, then it is the latter interpretation. but then I am not sure what is $h*x$

Comment: @JohnMa Ah! I see the mistake. What I really meant was the operation $\text{multiplication}$ doesn't have that property if $h, g, x \in \mathbb{Z}$, because one can multiply by $-1$. Does my edit make more sense?

Comment: I did not understand the second paragraph that much. Everything else was clear though, in my opinion.